# Algorithm to recreate a Splay tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, splay-trees

Let's say I have some splay tree as following:

[image]

I want to recrate the exact same Splay tree using `insert(key)` method. Is there an algorithm that given some Splay tree traversal (or any other representation) will create the same Splay tree?

In other words, assume you are using some online tool to [visualize](https://cmps-people.ok.ubc.ca/ylucet/DS/SplayTree.html) your Splay tree. What algorithm would you follow to recreate the above Splay tree?